# How to iterate over TreeMap<Integer, T> from end to beginning

Tags: java, treemap

I need to iterate through a `TreeMap<Integer, T> map` from the end to beginning. How to do so?

---

I have tried the same thing as the answer in posted topic below:

```
new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return o2.intValue() - o1.intValue();
    }
}
```

but this is not a solution, that's just reversing the order.

Comment: a duplicate of which question? This seems to be quite different than the "How to Print a treemap in reverse order". That questions (and certainly the answers) seems to focus on how to build a treemap using a custom (eg. reverse) ordering. This is how to take a TreeMap, in whatever order it is in, and iterate it in reverse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call [descendingMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#descendingMap%28%29) and iterate over the entry set from that map.